# How can I apply a template by name?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XSL file that makes use of an XML file. The XSL file needs to display the information found in the XML document twice, but slightly differently each time.

How can I declare different templates that have the same match, but specify which template I want to be called when using `<xsl:apply-templates select="...">...</>`

Comment: It sounds like you may be able to use the `mode` attribute (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#modes) although to give a more precise answer you might want to edit your question to show a sample of your XML and the output you expect. Thanks.

Comment: Since you specifically asked about template names, I observe that templates indeed can have names.  Template access by name is served by the `xsl:call-template` action, however, not (directly) by `xsl:apply-templates`.  If you want to override the normal priority rules for choosing between different templates that match the same node when you `apply-templates`, then you have the `mode` dimension to play with, as @TimC already said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I declare different templates that have the same match, but
>   specify which template I want to be called when using
>   ...

Use modes. In the template rule:

```
<xsl:template match="xyz" mode="mode1"/>
```

In the apply-templates call:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="abc" mode="mode1"/>
```

When searching for the "best fit" template rule, only template rules in the appropriate mode are considered.

Modes are available in all XSLT versions. In XSLT 3.0 you can declare properties of a mode, for example

```
<xsl:mode name="mode1" streamable="yes" on-no-match="fail"/>
```